# What is the best way to block the user from chatting in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**Data Structure**

```
Users
|
--- lvBnCNGuTahS9xjT51oB
    |
    --- Can Chat (Boolean)
```

I have the `Can Chat` field and if the value was true then the user can chat with others but if the value was false then the user cannot chat with others, The problem is when I ban the user will be banned forever, I solved the problem by convert `Can Chat` field to string instead of boolean type. If the user got ban then the value will look like this `Can Chat => false, 1761996174`

`1761996174` This is the timestamp that indicates when the ban will unlock.

I'm asking if there is a better way to do that, Or that way is the best?

Comment: The question is a bit broad as there are probably 100 different ways to do that. Also asking what *the best* way is to do something is high subjective (and opinionated) and is not well suited for SO. Is it not working now? How are you making the comparison with the server stored timestamp? How is the timestamp generated?

Comment: @Jay I did not start code yet because I'm drawing data structure first because this step will make it easy during programming. I'll compare timestamp using Firetore rules, Cloud Functions, or from the client-side, not decided yet. My way will work but I think it's a stupid way because if the value was `true` then I'll convert `Can Chat` field to boolean but if the value was `Can Chat => false, 1761996174` then I'll convert `Can Chat` field to string. How do you do it in your style?

Comment: I don't really have a style because there are too many ways to do this. Perhaps reversing the structure; keep a node with a key of `blocked` with a value of the time they are blocked until. If the node doesn't exist then obviously they are not block and can chat. That would be done client side. If the node does exist then they are blocked until the time stored in that node. You could also implement Rules to block a write unless some criteria are met - which is more server side. You could also implement Cloud functions etc etc. You should really try some code and see  what works for you.